# Why the result is always None?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
class Deck(object):
    def __init__(self,starting_cards = None):
            self._cards = starting_cards

    def get_cards(self):
        if self._cards==None:
            return []

        else:
            return self._cards
    def add_cards(self,new_cards):
        if self._cards == None:
            self._cards = []
            self._cards.extend(new_cards)
        else:
            self._cards.extend(new_cards)

class Player(object):
    def __init__(self,name):
        self._name= name
    def get_deck(self):
        return Deck()
```

So if I input:

```
a = Player('a')
b = [1,2,3,4]
a.get_deck.add_cards(b)
a.get_deck.get_cards
```

It just return `[]`, but is should be `[1,2,3,4]`, why?

But if I change 
    'def **init**(self,starting_cards = None):' 
to
    'def **init**(self,starting_cards = []):'
it could give the '[1,2,3,4]'

Comment: Take a close look at your `get_deck` function.

Comment: `a.get_deck.add_cards(b)` or `a.get_deck().add_cards(b)`

Comment: `[]` is an empty list, not `None`

Comment: On a side note... you've got a lot of `None` checks there... Why not do the `if None` check *once* in your `__init__` and where it is none, set `self._cards` to be an empty list `[]`... then you don't need to worry about it in your other instance methods.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you always returned new `Deck` instance in `get_deck()` function.
You should have `Deck` instance as member variable of `Player`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're never storing a players deck. Every time you call getDeck it looks to be creating a new deck object.

Comment: but if i change 'def __init__(self,starting_cards = None)' to 'def __init__(self,starting_cards = [])' . it works

Answer (score 0):

Second Aran-Fey's comment. Your `get_deck` function returns a deck, so calling`a.get_deck.add_cards(b)` will first return a deck, and add `b` cards to this deck, but this deck is not stored anywhere.

You could do 
`xyqrz = a.get_deck()` then `xyqrz.add_cards(b)` and call `xyqrz.get_cards()`.